# How to make RadioButton in Symfony Form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have form that i have to redo with Symfony Form but i stuck on this place:

```
<div class="currency-label">
    <input checked id="cur1" name="currency" type="radio">
    <label for="cur1">EURO</label>
</div>
<div class="currency-label active">
    <input id="cur2" name="currency" type="radio">
    <label for="cur2">USD</label>
</div>
```

This is how it looks:
[image: how it should look]

how to make radiobutton with Symfony Forms? 
In my form class i added:

```
->add('vacancyCurrency', RadioType::class, ['required' => false])
```

and to my template

```
{{ form_widget(form.vacancyCurrency) }}
```

my form became shorter and obviously no css :
[image: how it looks without css]
and if i add css class to form it looks differently :

```
{{ form_widget(form.vacancyCurrency, {'attr':
      {'class': 'currency-label'}
}) }}
```

[image: description 1]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So that is how i solved this, in template:

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
 {% form_theme form _self %}
 {% block choice_widget %}
     {% for child in form.vacancyCurrency %}
         <div class="currency-label">
             {{- form_widget(child) -}}
             {{- form_label(child, null) -}}
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
 {% endblock choice_widget %}
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

in form class:

```
->add('vacancyCurrency', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => [
        'USD' => 'USD',
        'RUB' => 'RUB',
    ],
    'expanded' => true,
])
```

and to make one of them active i set default data in model:

```
public $vacancyCurrency = 'RUB';
```

> Update

now i have interface for currency and use it in form class:

```
->add('currency', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'Валюта',
    'choices' => \array_combine(CurrencyInterface::ALL, CurrencyInterface::ALL)
])
```

Comment: To be on the safe side, add `'multiple'=>false` under `'expanded'=>true`

Comment: It doesn't show however, how this works, since you omit the setting of the (possibly local) form theme, please add that.

Comment: @Jakumi i updated my answer, hope it is looks more clear now. English isn't my native language so  if my answer isn't clear and you have some questions please ask.

Comment: The cleanest way I have found to not display inline radio buttons, without the risk of impacting all my other forms. Thank you !

Comment: In case you don't need to show the label, you can add ```{'label':false}``` inside the form_widget.

Answer (score 12):

The best way to do it is to render a `ChoiceType` as radio buttons:

```
->add(
    'vacancyCurrency', 
    ChoiceType::class, 
    [
        'choices' => [
            'US Dolar' => 'usd',
            'Euro' => 'eur',
        ],
    'expanded' => true
    ]
);
```

The ChoiceType field it's rendered as radio buttons when you have the options `multiple = false` and `expanded = true`. The option `multiple` is not in the code above because its default value is `false`. You can find more details [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)

**Edit:**

In your twig template, you just need to add:

```
{{ form_widget(form.vacancyCurrency) }}
```

**Edit 2**

You said in the comments to this answer that you need to put each radio button inside a `<div class="currency-label active">`. I believe you can't do it by setting attributes in the Symfony Form Field itself. The options you have there, like `choice_attr` operate in the `input`, not in the divs that surround it.

It's possible to achieve what you want, but you'll need to write some code and render the radio buttons by hand, like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Vacancy currency</label>
    {% for child in form.vacancyCurrency %}
        <div class="currency-label active">
            <label for="{{ child.vars.id }}" class="required">
                <input type="radio" id="{{ child.vars.id }}" name="{{ form.vars.id ~ '[' ~ form.vacancyCurrency.vars.name ~ ']' }}" required="required" class="checkbox" value="{{ child.vars.label }}">
                {{ child.vars.label }}
            </label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Of course, you can use some Javascript to do the job. For example, you can render the form field like:

```
{{ form_widget(form.vacancyCurrency) }}
```

It will add each radio button inside a div with `class="radio"`.

Then you can change the class to what you want as soon as the page is ready with some JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".radio").attr("class", "currency-label active");
});
```

Comment: Yes, i tried that way, but if in template i do:

```<div class="currency-label active">
       <!-- <input id="cur2" name="currency" type="radio"> -->
       {{ form_widget(form.vacancyCurrency, {'attr': {'type': 'radio'}, 'label': 'USD'} ) }}
</div>```

it breaks my `css` and i don't really understand why.

Comment: I edited my answer to add how to render the field in twig

Comment: Alas, it still break my css. Rows in form became shorter, that somehow depends on `<div>` tags.

Comment: Both buttons should be under the same `<div class="currency-label active">` or one `<div>` for each button?

Comment: It should be one `<div>` for each button

Comment: @Loctarogar, try `{{ form_row(form.vacancyCurrency) }}`

Comment: @Loctarogar I added an edit to my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Many Thanks! I edited your answer a bit but in general you was correct, this is how final version looks like:

Comment: ```{% for child in form.vacancyCurrency %}
                                            <div class="currency-label active">
                                                <input type="radio" id="{{ child.vars.id }}"
                                                       name="{{ form.vars.id ~ '[' ~ form.vacancyCurrency.vars.name ~ ']' }}">
                                                <label for="{{ child.vars.id }}">{{ child.vars.label }}</label>
                                            </div>
                                        {% endfor %}```

Comment: well, i didn't notice it at first, but that doesn't work properly so i unmarked your answer. sorry

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Caconde i updated my question with images. But for your suggestion to use `for loop` it shows what i need correctly but in  the bottom of form it shows `form.vacancy` widget second time.

Comment: I see. That is probably because you are rendering your form with `{{form_widget(form)}}` (that renders the full form) and creating the radio buttons by hand. It will generate the field duplication. You have to render all the form field by field. Check Symfony's docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) to see how to do it

Comment: @Caconde Don't think so, i generate field by field. But may be i am wrong, can you check ?
My gist with this form: https://gist.github.com/Loctarogar/f6ae81a6d5aad41b71d0e3137f28c727

Comment: @Caconde sounds like an endless story. one way is possibly `{{ form.subform.setRendered(true) }}` to stop it from being rendered again (which is usually necessary for all truly manually rendered forms) ... it's also why I almost always use local form themes. `{{ form_end(form) }}` will generally render the rest of the non-rendered elements, before closing the form ...