# How do I style child elements of a drop down list in a Symfony form

Tags: php, css, forms, symfony, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to style the dropdown options (label and checkbox) of a symfony form but am running into problems. I can style the rendered group of checkboxes and labels, but not each item (paired label + checkbox) individually.

I've attempted to style them by:

```
{{ form_widget(form.qualifications, {'attr': {'class':'d-block'} }) }}
```

But as detailed in the documentation, this only applies the styles to the parent element (the rendered group of options to select), not each individual option.

Here's the symfony form builder part which creates the widget

```
->add('qualifications', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Tag::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Select...',
                'choices' => $this->tagsService->getTagsQualificationLevels(),
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control-ajax-submit-on-change w-20',
                ]
            ])
```

I expect to be able to apply styles to the choices array, but am really stuck on how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the choice_attr option:

```
    ->add('qualifications', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Tag::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Select...',
                'choices' => $this->tagsService->getTagsQualificationLevels(),
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control-ajax-submit-on-change w-20',
                ],
                'choice_attr' => function($choiceValue, $key, $value) {
                    return ['class' => 'my_custom_choice_class'];
                },
            ])
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, thanks. This has gotten me as far as applying the class name to the checkbox, but nothing to the label. It also seems as if none of the styles I've declared in my scss file are being applied to the checkbox.

Comment: You can also use label_attr. Check out the docs here: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html#label-attr

Comment: Thanks Mihai, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try for loop in template?
I had similar problems with radiobutton, take a look: [How to make RadioButton in Symfony Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914944/how-to-make-radiobutton-in-symfony-form/57980275?noredirect=1#comment102395647_57980275)